# How do I get the group property of the DrawingObJects class?

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this subroutine, there are always two ungrouped shapes on the sheet "Symbol Editor" so CASE 2 is always executed.

This statement executes.

```
Selection.Name = "testThis"
```

With this statement:

```
Set grpShapes = Selection.Group
```

I get

> Runtime error 1004 Unable to get the group Property of the DrawingObJects class

1. Why can I assign a value to a selection.group "property", but cannot capture the object itself?
2. Semi related. Each shape has its own positioning coordinates, but once "grouped" the entire group can be "selected" and moved around a SHEET in unison.
   How is this done? Does the selection have its own positioning coordinate and each shape adjusts their coordinates accordingly?

```vb
Sub TestForGroups()
    Dim shps As Shapes: Set shps = Sheets("Symbol Editor").Shapes
    Dim grpShapes As GroupShapes 
    Dim TN As String
    
    Select Case shps.Count
        *Case 0
            TN = TypeName(Selection)
            MsgBox "There are no shapes ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
         Case 1
             shps.SelectAll
             TN = TypeName(Selection)
             If TN = "GroupObject" Then
                Selection.Ungroup
                MsgBox "Ungrouped a group ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
             Else
                MsgBox "One shape selected ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
             End If
             Debug.Print TypeName(Selection)
         Case Is > 1
             shps.SelectAll
             TN = TypeName(Selection)
             If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
                Selection.Group            
                MsgBox "Grouped all shapes ('" & TN & "').", vbInformation
                Selection.Name = "testThis"
                **Set grpShapes = Selection.Group** 
             End If
    End Select    
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the `GroupShapes` object, you go through the `GroupItems` like this:

```vb
Sub CreateMyGroup()
    Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
    Set thisSheet = Sheets("Symbol Editor")
    
    Dim allShapes As Shapes
    Set allShapes = thisSheet.Shapes
    
    allShapes.SelectAll
    If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
        Dim theGroup As Object
        Set theGroup = Selection.Group
        theGroup.Name = "MyBigGroup"
        
        Dim grpShapes As groupShapes
        Set grpShapes = theGroup.ShapeRange.GroupItems
        Debug.Print "shapes in this group = " & grpShapes.Count
    End If
End Sub
```